# I want to add "View Desktop Version" for mobile visitors for my wordpress site

Tags: responsive

I am trying to add a Desktop view button only for mobile visitors. if I can remove the responsive viewport meta there is a way to do that but I could not make it work. anybody can help me how can I do it for my Wordpress site?
here is a screenshot what I want to do https://prnt.sc/t3693k

Thanks

Comment: This entirely depends on how you make the decision between showing the mobile or desktop view. If you are doing this via media query (which I do recommend), you are better of improving the mobile view. If you really want to pursue this, you need a way to 'toggle' between the two views. Either store it in a cookie or some other semi persistent way of storing it for the specific visitor of your website. Your code that then determines what kind of view is being shown, uses that data stored for that specific user. Note: This will be very hard to properly cache.

Comment: thanks, actually by default it will be load proper responsive mode but if the user wants to see the desktop view I want a toggle to change it. is this view cookie will not help. I am still trying to find a proper solution. Thanks for your suggestion.